# R returns an error when I try to dissolve polygons' boundaries using the summarize function in the sf package. How to solve it?

Tags: r, r-sf, summarize

I'm using R's `summarize` function in the `sf` package to dissolve the boundaries of some polygons, but I'm having problems as it returns an error in some cases. To give a concrete example, when I try to dissolve the district boundaries of the state of California in the [shape file](https://cdmaps.polisci.ucla.edu/) for the 80th US Congress, I get the following error:

```
Error:
! Assigned data `geom` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 1 row.
x Assigned data has 2 rows.
i Row updates require a list value. Do you need `list()` or `as.list()`?
```

The code used is the following:

```
dfs <- {st_read('D:/Data/districts080.shp') %>% 
    select(., STATENAME, DISTRICT) %>% 
    filter(., STATENAME == 'California') %>% 
    group_by(., STATENAME) %>% summarize(.)}
```

It works smoothly in other cases (for instance, as in the case of Alabama).

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You don;t need all those period marks, ```select(., STATENAME, DISTRICT)``` can just be s```select( STATENAME, DISTRICT)```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @user438383. I knew that it is not necessary to include those period marks, but I think that including it makes the code clearer and, in some sense, it makes it more appropriate (from a mathematical perspective). Moreover, when passing some result to the second argument of a function (that is wrapped in curly brackets), it makes it visually easy to spot where I'm passing the result to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sf:::summarise.sf` method actually uses the `st_union` function under the hood, but in the case of this shapefile the alignment seems imperfect. We can get round this by putting a small buffer around each polygon before specifically calling `st_union`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

temp  <- tempfile()

URL <- "https://cdmaps.polisci.ucla.edu/shp/districts080.zip"
download.file(URL, temp)
unzip(zipfile = temp)

dfs <- st_read("districtShapes/districts080.shp") %>% 
  select(STATENAME, DISTRICT) %>% 
  filter(STATENAME == 'California') %>%
  mutate(geometry = st_sfc(lapply(geometry, function(x) st_buffer(x, 0.0001)), 
                           crs = st_crs(.))) %>%
  st_union() %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  mutate(STATENAME = "California") %>%
  rename(geometry = x)

ggplot(dfs) + 
  geom_sf(fill = "white")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution, @allan-cameron. I didn't know about this trick; it will help me a lot.